# put variable in return confirm()

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPresent" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('N student Absent?');"  />
```

I want to replace this "N" with one server side variable (lstAbsent.Count)

I have Tried

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPresent" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm("+lstAbsent.Count+" student Absent?');"  />
```

and

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPresent" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm(''"+lstAbsent.Count+"' student Absent?');"  />
```

But it is not working .....What I am missing ?

Comment: Put your javascript to a function and example like this

return confirm( <%=lstAbsent.Count %> + ' student Absent?');
Try to not put everything in 1 line due to Control might not support "+ + " in between

Answer (score 1):

You can define a JS function like this:-

```
 function confirmStudentsMsg()
 {
     var studentsAbsent = '<%= lstAbsent.Count %>';
     return confirm(studentsAbsent + ' student(s) absent?');
 }
```

Then, Simply call it from your button click:-

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPresent" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirmStudentsMsg();" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `OnClientClick` in your code-behind.

```
 btnPresent.OnClientClick = 
   string.Format("return confirm('{0} student Absent?');", lstAbsent.Count);
```

Unfortunately it is not possible to use inline code blocks `<%= %>` on the attributes of server side controls.  (There is an exception to this rule, and that is you **can** use databinding inline-code blocks `<%# %>` on the attributes of controls within things like `<asp:Repeater>` and `<asp:GridView>`)